# Can't require jquery-ui in rails app, fake name doesn't cause an error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to use `jquery-ui-rails` in my rails app (running [spree 3.0](https://github.com/spree/spree)).

```
$ bundle list | grep jq
  * jquery-rails (4.0.5)
  * jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get jquery-ui to load (neither the css or the js file). Things I've tried in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui/menu
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

None of these seemed to make a difference, and I even tried

```
//= require file-that-does-not-exist
```

and saw no error. What's going on here? Is the file even being loaded?

Comment: If nothing works add the files manually. Just to verify the issue.

Comment: @MuaazRafi What do you mean exactly? Add which files to where?

Comment: In application.js contains the manifesto of all javascript files, include the jquery ui files manually just to verify if the javascript is being added the asset pipeline or not.

Comment: @MuaazRafi It is not, that's my problem.

Comment: You are using gem, i am asking manually place files in assets/javascript folder or use the vendor folder whatever you prefer and test that files do included when assets compiles by server in development mood.

Comment: @MuaazRafi Oh I see. Tried that, same problem.

Comment: This might seem pretty basic but does your `/views/layouts/application.html.erb` contain `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`? Sprockets won't even try to compile the file (in dev) unless you actually include the javascript in your views.

Comment: @max That got me in the right direction, thanks. Just needed to look at spree's documentation *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the proper way to add assets when using spree. Spree's main layout does **not** include the `application.js` file! The proper way to include more assets is documented here: https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/asset.html

In short, add the require statements to `app/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js`. This file is loaded by spree. If you want to add it to the backend as well, add it to `app/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/all.js`. Stylesheets go in `app/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.js` and `app/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/all.js` as you might expect. You may want to add

```
//= require application
```

to the `all.js` files and

```
/*
 *= require application
 */
```

to the `all.css` files to make things behave as expected, or add a warning to the top of your `application` files something like:

```
!!!!! THIS FILE IS NOT LOADED BY SPREE. ADDING THINGS HERE DOES NOTHING !!!!!
```

It may save you hours and hours of work in the future.